# Is it possible to make 3D pie chart using chart.js?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have successfully made 2D pie chart using chart.js but i want to give it 3D effect.

i expect 3D pie chart using chart.js

Comment: no, it isn't possible based on the documentation, look at [highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/3d-pie) if you want to do 3d pie chart

Comment: No, even though the logo for the organisation's website is a 3D chart that's a red herring.

Answer (score -1):

It's not possible, to plot I recommend [plotly.js](https://plotly.com/javascript/), it's easy to use and fit's most cases. For more complex and animated charts I would go with [Three.js](https://threejs.org/), highly customizable but somewhat complex to use.

Comment: plotty.js doesn't has a 3D Pie as the user it's asking for.